# Wordpress incorret password for username or email, added using "wp_insert_user"

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

So i have created my own user, using below code. I am more than certain that i have a correct password when i login. But for some reason that I dont know i always have "The password you entered for the email address/username is incorrect". Can someone shed some light on me!!!

```
 function insert_into_wp_users(){
    // Check for nonce security      
    if (!wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], 'active-aupair-nonce-string' ) ) {
        die();
    }
    $user_id = wp_insert_user( array(
       'user_email'   => $_POST['email'],
       'user_password'=> $_POST['password'],
    //    'first_name'   => $_POST['firstName'],
    //    'last_name'    => $_POST['lastName'],
       'user_login'   => $_POST['userLogin'],
       'role'         => 'subscriber'
     ));
     if( is_wp_error( $user_id  ) ) {
        wp_send_json_error($user_id->get_error_message());
    } else {
        wp_send_json_success($user_id);
    }
    die();
}
```

P.S I confirm that my user exist. Wordpress just cant validate the password.

Comment: I'd first dump `$_POST` to make sure that there's nothing weird in there, like strange characters from unexpected encodings, or whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

You're using `user_password` instead of `user_pass`.

[*I lost an hour using your parameters.*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MXcMV-d_2Js)

---

Additionally, it seems that you should also be able to use [`wp_create_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_user/) as you're not doing anything fancy.

> ### [`wp_create_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_user/)
>
> Creates a new user with just the username, password, and email. For more complex user creation use [`wp_insert_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/) to specify more information.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpso66859906' );
if ( ! function_exists( 'wpso66859906' ) ) {
    function wpso66859906() {

        $user = 'thomas';
        $email = 'thomas@pesquet.com';
        $password = 'password';

        if ( ! username_exists( sanitize_user( $user ) ) && is_email( sanitize_email( $email ) ) && ! email_exists( sanitize_email( $email ) ) ) {
            
            wp_create_user( sanitize_user( $user ), trim( $password ), sanitize_email( $email ) );
            
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: thank you so mucchhhh, i have spent my entire night to this. I am going to use the "wp_insert_user" as i need to define the users role.

Answer (score 0):

your password is always set to blank because you are using the wrong property, it must be `user_pass` not `user_password` that why you not able to login